# Trying to create a menu toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a menu toggle like on mobile for the desktop also with hide and show functionality but I am not able to do so.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menuMobileToggle").click(function() {
        $(".CategoryList").slideToggle(700);
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="top-nav">
    <div class="CategoryList" id="TopCategoryList">
        <div class="SideCategoryListClassic">
            <nav>
                <ul class="category-list" style="padding-top: 3px;">
                    <li class=""><a href="/motorcycle-tire-warmers">MOTO-D Tire Warmers</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/pro-series-motorcycle-stands">MOTO-D Stands</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/cnc-motorcycle-parts">Bonamici Rearsets</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/motorcycle-gps-lap-timer">MOTO-D "Next" GPS Lap Timer</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/motorcycle-undersuits-and-baselayers">MOTO-D Undersuit</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/spark-italy-exhaust-technologies">Spark Italy Exhausts</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="/performance-riding-motorcycle-accessories">Accessories</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>

 <a href="#" id="menuMobileToggle">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery to toggle navigation menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887776/jquery-to-toggle-navigation-menu)

Comment: Nope sorry,its not what i want

Comment: That seems to work fine. What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your code is incomplete and you must include jquery library. check below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#menuMobileToggle").click(function() {
    $(".CategoryList").slideToggle(700);
  });
});
```

```css
.CategoryList {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top-nav">
  <a href="#" id="menuMobileToggle">Menu</a>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="CategoryList" id="TopCategoryList">
    <div class="SideCategoryListClassic">
      <nav>
        <ul class="category-list" style="padding-top: 3px;">
          <li class=""><a href="/motorcycle-tire-warmers">MOTO-D Tire Warmers</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="/pro-series-motorcycle-stands">MOTO-D Stands</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="/cnc-motorcycle-parts">Bonamici Rearsets</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="/motorcycle-gps-lap-timer">MOTO-D "Next" GPS Lap Timer</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="/motorcycle-undersuits-and-baselayers">MOTO-D Undersuit</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="/spark-italy-exhaust-technologies">Spark Italy Exhausts</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="/performance-riding-motorcycle-accessories">Accessories</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```